# Reading from a file in Java when the there are two lines of input

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader, filereader

I'm a beginner in Java, so I was wondering if someone could help me with my problem. I am doing the USACO bronze problem, Square Pasture.

Here is my code.

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("square.in"));
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("square.out")),true);
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(in.readLine());
int smallestX = 10;
int largestX = 0;
int smallestY = 10;
int largestY = 0;
for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {
  int xLow=Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
  int yLow=Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
  int xHigh=Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
  int yHigh=Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
  if(xLow < smallestX)
    smallestX = xLow;
  if(xHigh > largestX)
    largestX = xHigh;
  if(yLow < smallestY)
    smallestY = yLow;
  if(yHigh > largestY)
    largestY = yHigh;
}
int ydistance=largestY-smallestY;
int xdistance=largestX-smallestX;
int maxi=Math.max(ydistance,xdistance);
int ans=maxi*maxi;
out.print (ans);
out.close();
```

The sample input in this problem is

```
6 6 8 8
1 8 4 9
```

I am getting an error that says:
java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(Unknown Source)

I believe this is happening because my code keeps checking the same line. My code runs perfectly when the input is

```
6 6 8 8 1 8 4 9
```

I looked at similar problems on StackOverflow but was not able to find any.

Comment: I would be best to use a debugger to find the line in which it was failing. Or, you could show us the complete stack trace, and show us the line on which it fails.

Comment: You read one line from a file into a tokenizer (which has 4 integer numbers) and then try to read the 4 numbers _twice_

Answer (score 1):

Move `StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(in.readLine());` into the loop as the first line.